# msbuild failure building C++ project not finding buildtools V143

Tags: c++, msbuild

I upgraded to VS2022. All my projects build fine when I build using VS 2022.
But my C++ project project fails to build when I use the build definition to build it on the same build machine that has VS2022 installed. When I use the build definition the solution is built using msbuild and it fails to build the C++ project and fails with this error:
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets (514): Specified platform toolset (v143) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.

VCTargetsPath was not set for me and I set it to
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170 but it still fails.
The buildtool V143 is installed I have no problem building the project if I build using V143 from Visual studio.

My questions are:
Why does msbuild complain that buildtool v143 is not installed?
Why does it searches for C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64 instead of C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170?

Also there is no Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets in
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170.

Before VS2022 I had VS 2019 and msbuild was working.

Comment: Presumably some environmental difference. How are you running msbuild (e.g. what command shell are you running it in)?

Comment: Not from command shell. This is the automated build. So I do not know how it is being run and it runs under a  service account.

Comment: Well, perhaps that platform toolset is not installed ‍♂️  If you run the Visual Installer, it will tell you.

Comment: @aliahaider Well I think that it is highky likely that the automated build environment is the problem. But of course I am only speculating.

Comment: The C++ tools are an optional workload in the Visual Studio installer and I concur that it sounds like the VS2022 install on the host for the build agent doesn't have the C++ workload.